# Двухточечный кросинговер

Tags: алгоритм

Столкнулся с такой задачей: определить двухточечный кросинговер для следующих особей при выборе для отца точек кросинговера 4, 8.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю как это делать в случае если строки одинаковой длины и точки кросинговера заданы как для отца так и для матери, а как в этом случае поступать я не знаю...
Информации особой на этот счет нет.
Нашел немного в [этой книге](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=_LETCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80&source=bl&ots=fp3TP00cvS&sig=chyGQM_haZEA3d22u_ylTP3Q_b8&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzie-o4NDYAhVGDCwKHS7nAZ8Q6AEIWTAL#v=onepage&q=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80&f=false), но там все равно немного другой случай

Может кто-то сталкивался с этим, буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: Книга не доступна. Страницы не отображаются (их гугл закрывает). Поясните термин кросинговер.

Comment: Ну, я бы читал Альбертса и Уотсона "Молекулярная биология клетки" (благо в сети есть PFD этой замечательной книги"), чтобы решить такую задачу.

Comment: @hedgehogues, под кросинговером или кросовером, я понимаю генетический оператор срещевания, благодаря которому, происходит обмен генетическим материалом между особями.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, спасибо большое за книгу. Я видимо не совсем точно описал мою проблему, за что извиняюсь. Моя задача является частью реализации генетического алгоритма, который в свою очередь, все таки является упрощением реальных биологических процессов. Одним из этапов этого алгоритма является получение потомков, выбранных пар родителей, которое достигается благодаря оператору кроссинговера. Мне как раз и нужно выполнить только скрещевание.

Comment: Непонятно, что этот оператор представляет по отношения к Вашим обозначениям

Comment: @hedgehogues, вот это я и сам пытаюсь понять:)
Вот так выглядит задание...

Comment: Что такое *C* в таблице?